# Ignore "cannot stat" error (file does not exist) for cp in tcsh script

Tags: makefile, tcsh

I have makefile that uses tcsh shell (I know this is not recommended, but it is a requirement). I don't want it to break if `a.txt` does not exist, but I want it to continue to the next command. How do I do this?

```
setup:
   cp -rf a.txt b.txt; \
   [other things that should be executed]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
([ -f a.txt ] && cp a.txt b.txt); ls
```

This will work both in C shells and Bourne shells

- `[ -f a.txt ]` uses the `test` (aka. `[`) command to check if `a.txt` exists.
- The `&&` is the "and" operator, if only executes the next command (`cp`) if the preceding commands (`[`) succeeds.
- We wrap this in parenthesis (`(...)`) to group it together, so we can add a `;` and run more commands unaffected by the file test.

We could also use the C shell's built-in `if`, but this is more portable and familiar for people not familiar with csh (ie. most people).